# PHP - Value of input isn't shown

Tags: php, html, sql-server

I am retrieving data from mysqlserver row item to the value of the input text box but the value is not showing when the page loads. And I can't seem to get the value of the input box to show. Anyone knows what is wrong?

```
<?php           
        if(isset($_COOKIE["email"]))
        {               
            $emailAddress = $_COOKIE["email"];
            $password = $_COOKIE["password"];               
            include('connectDB.php');
            $select = "SELECT * FROM P_Profile WHERE P_EmailAddress = '$emailAddress' AND P_Password='$password'";              
            mysql_select_db("lotusbs", GetConnection()) or die(mysql_error());                  
            $result = mysql_query($select) or die(mysql_error());               
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($result)                   
            ?>              
                <div class="signupcontainer">
                    <div class="contentsignup" style="margin-top:20px;">                        
                    <div class="textboxsignup"><span class="signuptbspan" style="Display:none;">First name</span><input value="<?php echo $row['P_FirstName'];?>" name="txtfirstname" id="txtfirstname" type="text"/></div>
                        <div class="signupinfo">Enter first name</div>
                        <div class="signupinfoerror">Must Enter first name</div>
```

Comment: what does `var_dump($_COOKIE);` give you?

Comment: @Mike, the cookie is fine but the input value isnt being set this is the html when the form loads <input id="txtfirstname" type="text" name="txtfirstname" value="John">

Comment: `$_COOKIE["password"];` sounds really a bad thing

Comment: definitely what Damien Pirsy said.

Comment: im new to php im a vb.net web developer and im just using php becuase my client wanted that. but i really need to get this done by 6 pm today

Answer (score 1):

Try to debug this script for instance:

1. Check if the script passes the if( isset($_coo....) bit by echoing inside the true-clause.
2. echo $select, after the mysql-query was formed as a string, and try this out in the phpmyadmin. Check if the query is error-less and if the variables passed are included in the right way.
3. Try dumping the $row variable right before closing php ?> this way you will no if the result is passed to the row-variable.

Answer (score 1):

Here a couple possibilities:

- The column might not exist
- The row might not exist
- The connection might have failed or you might have chosen the wrong database.

And there is one other thing that you should consider changing. You save the password unencrypted and unencoded with cookies. This means that you can actually find people their passwords in the cookies. This could have quite big consequences because if the user uses that same info on a other website people can hack them really easily.

Answer (score 1):

Before doing this :

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result)
```

You should always check whether or not the query has fetched you any rows from the table by doing this :

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result)) {
    // fetch the rows here and do other stuff
}
else {
    echo "Record was not found !";
}
```

which will tell you that some records are returned by the query. If your getting the output as "Record not found" then there is something wrong with your SQL query. Also `mysql_fetch_array()` gives you an array which is to be accessed as `$row[0]`. If you want to access it as an associative array like `$row['P_FirstName']` then, you need to call the function `mysql_fetch_assoc()`.